# Affordable and accessible accommodation options with car parking near Paris?

Tags: budget, public-transport, france, accommodation, paris

I am planning to visit Paris soon, but the hotel and parking costs are a major issue for me. For this reason, I am considering to stay in a hotel outside of Paris, with easy public transport connections to the center of Paris.

Is there anybody who can recommend any locations for this?

I would prefer a town North of Paris, as I am driving there from Belgium. This is not a "must", though.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: Up to 80 euro per night would be ideal.

Comment: Did you have a look to Clichy?

Answer (score 9):

There are various low-budget hotels offering basic rooms around Paris. [Hotels Formule 1 (F1) by Accor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Formule_1) is one such franchise. The rooms are pretty basic, in other words you get what you pay for. These hotels are usually found outside the city, and (arguably) for this reason offer free car parking to their guests. Quoting from the [linked Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Formule_1), here is the description of the no-frills rooms:

> The rooms are very basic and whitewashed. The rooms typically each contain a small desk, a television (with cable and international channels dependent on location), a double bed or a double bed with a bunk above, and a sink. There is no toilet or shower in the room; bathing facilities are provided by single-person showers and toilets accessible from the common hallways.

Other low-budget hotels include [Ibis Budget](http://www.ibis.com/fr/france/discovering-ibis-budget-hotel/index.shtml), [Ibis Styles](http://www.ibis.com/fr/france/discovering-ibis-styles-hotel/index.shtml) (both by Accor), [Première Classe](http://www.premiereclasse.com/en), [Campanile](http://www.campanile.com/en) and [Balladins](https://www.balladins.com/). Their facilities are slightly less spartan, and usually offer en-suite rooms as opposed to F1 hotels which do not. Of course the price per room will be higher than F1 hotels, but they might still fit your 80`EUR` budget.

[There is one F1 Hotel/Ibis Budget in Saint-Denis in the North of Paris.](http://www.hotelf1.com/fr/hotel-3072-formule-1-hotelf1-saint-denis-stade/location.shtml) From [the nearby La Plaine - Stade de France](https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/La+Plaine+-+Stade+de+France,+Saint-Denis/Hotel+ibis+Saint+Denis+Stade+Sud,+Rue+de+la+Cokerie,+Av+Francis+Pressense,+93210+LA+Plaine+Saint+Denis/@48.9195447,2.3614147,17z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66ea2b85e0e2f:0xb284521d0a301956!2m2!1d2.361655!2d48.9175!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66eb9f701ef8b:0xdfa13ad112bb960!2m2!1d2.364045!2d48.921237) station you can access the city easily using the RER-B (blue line) which takes you straight to the city centre (Châtelet Les-Halles). It might be worth emailing and asking if this hotel is more F1 or Ibis Budget in terms of accommodation (i.e. does it have en-suite rooms or not), since this isn't clear from the hotel website.

Comment: +1 for budget hotel chains. There are others you could perhaps mention in your answer, most of them (like Première Classe) with private toilets/shower in the room. Given the OP's budget, he could probably also look at slightly more expensive chains hotels like Balladins, Campanile, etc. which are also typically located in the same areas than budget hotels. Incidentally, the Wikipedia page is a bit confusing but I was under the impression that Ibis Budget hotels did have en-suite rooms, as did Etap Hotels before them. I think the hotels with shared bathrooms are still branded F1.

Answer (score 6):

A simple search on [booking.com](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?sid=eabc399dbfabe745d4359c56d0c80a9a;dcid=1;checkin=2015-05-21;checkout=2015-05-22;city=-1456928;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;dcsc=1;nflt=review_score%3D70%3B;no_rooms=1;review_score_group=empty;ssb=empty&;order=price_for_two) shows that there are rooms available in the city starting from 68 euro per night for a double room on a date that I've chosen randomly since I don't know your dates. I set the minimum review score as 7, since the ones lower than that have been very disappointing to my experience.

There is the map option, where you could see tons of hotels and their prices for the corresponding dates, but unfortunately it doesn't filter out the ones on the map based on your choices and availability on the date you entered. This feature might be added in the near future though.

Edit: Turns out, you can limit your search for places with parking on booking.com, among many other options you can find on the left side under *Facility*. Here's the [updated link](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?sid=eabc399dbfabe745d4359c56d0c80a9a;dcid=1;checkin=2015-05-21;checkout=2015-05-22;city=-1456928;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;dcsc=1;dtdisc=0;hlrd=0;hyb_red=0;inac=0;nha_red=0;no_rooms=1;order=price_for_two;redirected_from_city=0;redirected_from_landmark=0;redirected_from_region=0;review_score_group=empty;score_min=0;ss_all=0;ssb=empty;sshis=0&;;nflt=review_score%3D70%3Bhotelfacility%3D2%3B;unchecked_filter=facilities) taking that into account.

Comment: You are missing the car parking requirement set by the OP. ;)

Comment: Well, this makes yours the better response, but mine might be useful for someone too :)

Comment: Yup didn't mean to bring you answer down. ;) I was just hinting at the fact that you overlooked a criteria set by the OP. More interesting would be to know if booking.com allows to search for hotels with car parks. Is that the case?

Comment: Apparently it is possible, that just never occurred to me. I updated the answer to reflect that, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 5):

Did you have a look at those sites ?

- [airbnb.fr](https://www.airbnb.fr/)
- [sejourning.com](https://www.sejourning.com/)
- [bedycasa.com](http://www.bedycasa.com/)

Here is a comparison (in french) of the three ones among other competitors:

[image: Comparison of Airbnb, Sejourning and BedyCasa among other competitors]

On the other hand, you could try to find a flat in **Clichy**. It is well connected with the subway. There are 10mn only between Mairie de Clichy and Gare Saint-Lazare. From Clichy you need around 2h30 to reach the belgium border.

---

Source: [comment-economiser.fr](http://www.comment-economiser.fr/comparatif-sites-location-courte-duree-appart-particuliers.html)

Comment: The comparison matrix is for renters, not for travellers.

Comment: @FrancoisB. The second, fifth, sixth,seventh and eighth columns from the left are for travellers.